# Which components of VTD xml are thread safe?

Tags: vtd-xml

Using VTD 2.11

Can VTDGen be init once and used by multiple threads?

For instance I want to use it in a servlet so the VTGen gets initialized once when the servlet get initialized and then each request coming in parse what ever document is received.

Same for AutoPilot I would figure I can set my XPATH once and then keep rebinding it each new navigation?

Comment: What you described is totally doable, this is not a multi-threading related issue really...

Comment: I know! But I have a 50-60 node document I need to read 30 of those values. That means I need 30 autopilots? And does that mean I need to pool all 30 autopilots. It would be nice if the API allowed the autopilot to be init once and then reused as many times as we want. Instead of having to create a pool! Creat autopilots and XPATH should be a one time config. That can be used accross the application and we should not have to create our own pool to manage the xpaths. But ok I guess for now.

Comment: VTDGen instantiation cost is super low, literally nothing really, creat multiple VTDGen instances is not CPU nor memory intensive at all. AutoPilot instantiation with XPath on the other hand is totally different issue.

Comment: 30 autoPilots? Do you need 30 xpath expressions?

Comment: Yes, understood. And yes I have a small document but complex structure and I need to read most values. I'm following the data bind example. Maybe is not the best solution. Basically I need to do a transform of the document to another format. My idea is to bind to a POJO and then convert that Pojo to the other format. Another option is while in the iterating loop do a bunch of case statements and convert like that. Or while Iterating put everything in a Hashmap and then pull info from there and convert. What would be a good way to transform XML to another format using VTD then?

Comment: If the navigation is super complex, have you considered using VTDNav's API to manually navigate the tree structure? This is an alternative to XPath, but can be actually easier to implement

Comment: Do you mean autopilot selectElement()?

So create 1 and only 1 AutoPilot and bind to VTDNav and use a bunch of selectElement calls?

Comment: Is it in your example codes?

Comment: No, by using VTDNav's toElement()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VTD-XML can be initiated once and used many many times. But because VTDGen's initialization cost is super low, instantiating multiple copies of it incurs little cost...

AutoPilot is also designed to be reused... it is intimately linked to an XPath expression.

However, there are many circumstances in which it makes sense to assign AutoPilot instances of to each thread...each of those instances refers to the same xpath...

As an example:

```
AutoPilot ap1 = new AutoPilot();
AutoPilot ap2 = new AutoPilot();

ap1.selectXpath("/a/b/c") // assign to thread 1
ap2.selectXPath("/a/b/c"); // assigned to thread2,
```

Although ap1 and ap2 select the same xpath, they are two distinct xpath objects, and can be evaluated independently by 2 threads...which is better than trying to share a single AutoPilot between 2 threads... which leads to undesirable thread contention...